# "Go to URL" not work when URL is formed by parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We have a report built with SQL Server 2016 report builder. One of placeholder is showing an "ID" value with "Action = Go to URL". The URL value is form by expression. The expression is:

```
="https://mycompanysite.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=" & Fields!ID.Value
```

Above setup works. However I want to input the site URL with parameter. So I changed to:

```
=Parameters!SiteURL.Value & "_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=" & Fields!ID.Value
```

The SiteURL parameter have default value = "https://mycompanysite.com/"

Now the report DO NOT have links. It is **NOT broken links** but there is **NO LINK**. The "ID" value is showing up fine.

What could be the problem and how to work around it?

I tested with Report builder Preview, the link is working fine. However after I upload the report to report server there is no LINK.

Comment: how are you passing value to parameter, have you given it default value or passing per hand or taking it from some stored procedure or something?

Comment: Yes, in the rdl (report file) I have defined default value for parameter (by directly type in the string value, not querystring, store proc, datasource)

Comment: you mentioned in question ID value is showing up fine. Is your parameter value showing up fine? did you checked that? I would suggest add a dummy textbox and set parameter value there to see what the output is.

Comment: Yes, the ID value is showing up fine. If I setup a textbox to display the URL, it is showing up "#ERROR". Although I don't know which part my syntax is wrong.

Comment: No just try to see only parameter value, don’t try to crate a url we want to check if it does return correct value which you gave as a parameter.  Parameters!SiteURL.Value